# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang$Enum in Jenkins 2.0 while executing DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, enums, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a test and production Jenkins 2.0 instance (2.19.3). I am using the Job DSL plugin (1.53) to generate Pipeline DSL for a number of different branches.

I installed and upgraded all my plugins on the test instance, and verified that the seed jobs could build. After doing the same on the production instance, I am getting this error when running seed jobs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang$Enum
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:425)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 80 more
ERROR: Type java.lang$Enum not present
```

additonalClasspath is set to src/main/groovy

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/snKYu9beNl8) is the only other example I've seen of the same problem. I can modify the enum to a set of String constants as well, but would prefer to resolve the root cause of the problem.

Any suggestions on how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to figure out **why** this is happening, but after encountering this myself, I have found that restarting the service resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fixed issue in groovy 2.4.11
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8160